# load json data and display into datatable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, timestamp, epoch

```
     {
"status": done
"msg": "Got all leaves",
"data": [
{
"_id": "63b26e351bc7d25e5b7a1ebb",
"reason": "fever",
"date": 1672511400000,
"type": "tab1",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": 63b26fb91bc7d25e5b7a1ee8
"reason": "sick",
"date": 1672511400000,
"type": "tab1",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "63b26dcc1bc7d25e5b7a1eb",
"reason": "familyfunction",
"date": 1672511400000,
"type": "tab2",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "63b26fcb1bc7d25e5b7a1ef3",
"reason": "urgent leave",
"date": 1672511400000,
"type": "tab1",
"__v": 0
}
]
}
```

this is the json data.

I have two tabs called tab1 & tab2. I need to show a data each of specific tabs, and epoch vale also changed into datetime stamp.
example: if I pressed the tab1:

[image: result....]

and same like if I pressed the tab 2.

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve your output you can use `Table` widget.

For reference please refer to [this link](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-table-in-flutter-28726b28b5d6#:%7E:text=The%20Table%20widget%20in%20flutter,Google%20Developers).

And for JSON data, you can convert your JSON data into a Model class and make a list of that model class.

To convert JSON data to Model Class, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946696/flutter-how-to-convert-json-to-model-class-in-dart).

Comment: Please do not write an answer where the actual solution is not contained in the answer - but is only available via a link to an external location. Instead, provide enough details to make your answer self-contained. See [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/671985) and also [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).